# Who is honest? Who lies?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, permutations

A bioinformatics department at a University has 100 professors- some are honest and
hardworking, while others are deceitful & do not like students. The honest prof. always tell
the truth, while the deceitful ones sometimes tell the truth and at other times lie. You can ask
any professor Y the following question: “Professor Y, is Prof. X honest?” Y will answer either
“Yes” or “No”. Design an algorithm which will help you figure out which Profs are honest and
which lie. What is the minimum number of questions you need for this purpose? [It is known
that there are more honest Prof. than deceitful Profs]

Question is taken from a book. I really can't solve this problem. Can somebody help?

Comment: Can you have $X=Y$? So that you ask professor $Y$, if professor $Y$ himself is honest?

Comment: "Linear algebra"...?

Answer (score 0):

If you pair up the professors and ask each about the other, there are a few outcomes:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
\text{Prof }1&\text{Prof }2&1\to 2&2\to 1 \\ \hline
H & H & H & H \\ \hline
H & D & D & H \\
  &   & D & D \\ \hline
D & H & H & D \\ 
  &   & D & D \\ \hline
D & D & H & H \\ 
  &   & D & H \\ 
  &   & H & D \\ 
  &   & D & D \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

As you can see, each professor saying the other is honest can only occur if the two are the same (both honest or both dishonest). We can use this to identify an honest professor, who can then tell us all about the remaining professors.

Since there are more honest professors than dishonest we will get at least one pairing of honest professors, and for each pairing of dishonest professors we will get another pairing of honest professors. So there will always be more honest professors than dishonest among the possible [HH] reporting pairs.

We can then iteratively pick one each from these pairs to produce a new pool (for odd numbers, one professor can wait until the next round) to make a new set of tests, each time with a surplus of honest professors. The final professor (and all his prior companions, etc) will be honest, and we can ask any one of them about the remaining professors.